# When to declare variables in a class definition to NULL value?

Tags: php

What is the difference in these two examples?

```
class cl_Configuration
{
   private static $_instance = NULL;

   ...
```

and

```
class cl_Configuration
{
   private static $_instance;

   ...
```

Comment: Doesn't the first return a `true` on `isset($this->_instance)` and the second a `false`?

Comment: @CamilStaps No, both are false, as NULL is always false for `isset()`. http://codepad.viper-7.com/1SUnXv

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski okay, was guessing there :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are exactly the same. Declaring a PHP class property without a value will set the "value" to NULL by default unless implied otherwise, inherited, or overwritten.

You can prove this yourself with a simple test:
See the [PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/pqz-hk5) for the code below.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class cl_Configuration {
    public static $_instance = NULL;
}

class cl_Configuration_2 {
    public static $_instance;
}

var_dump(cl_Configuration::$_instance);
var_dump(cl_Configuration_2::$_instance);
```

Comment: I tested it before, but I was wondering if there is some other meaning, thx!